# Flutter app user authentication is working but data not store in the firestore but sometime ago it was working fine now its showing exception

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

Below exception showing in the debug console:
Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.

I want to store the data in the firestore.

Comment: Try to run the app in a real physical device. Sometimes this issue happens in Emulators, or it might be a network connection issue. Connect a physical device and run.